# Golang SDK for Google cloud storage : Multipart download

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Using GoLang SDK for google cloud storage.

Cannot find how to download files in chunks.

Comment: Please, provide more information what you mean by downloading files in chunks. There is documentation for Google Cloud Storage: https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage. As you can see it exposes a bucket objects as a regular reader interface. You could implement your own reader however you need to.

Comment: Downloading file in chunks means downloading file in chunks. That's plain english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Cloud documentation says to download an object from Cloud Storage, you should use the following:

```
rc, err := client.Bucket(bucket).Object(object).NewReader(ctx)
if err != nil {
        return nil, err
}
defer rc.Close()

data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rc)
if err != nil {
        return nil, err
}
return data, nil
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-code_sample

Given their SDK returns an `io.Reader`, you don't need to worry about the underlying method being used to be able to reference the download in chunks (although, quickly looking through their source, it just implements `http.NewRequest`, which does what you want, using the same logic).

The reason it doesn't seem to "chunked" from their example is because of the usage of `ioutil.ReadAll`, which although great for simple use cases, extracts all of the `Reader`s data into memory (meaning it also has to wait for the data to become available).

For a better understanding of how to deal with a `Reader` in steps, I recommend taking a look at https://tour.golang.org/methods/21 for a tour of `io.Reader` and how you can use it more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks.Yes, I was following that example but I was not sure how the underlying SDK works and if it actually downloads the complete file no matter how I use the io Reader.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this gives you what you need then